# custom cache alignment in rust

Tags: caching, rust

How can I optimize the performance of my RowMatrix struct in Rust for large number of rows?

I have a matrix defined in a RowMajor form using a struct in Rust as follows:

```
pub struct RowMatrix
{
    data: Vec<[usize; 8]>,
    width: usize,
}
```

Each row is broken down into an array of 8 elements and stacked one after the other in the `data` vector. For example, if the width is 64, then, the first 8 elements in the vector represent the first row, the next 8 elements represent the second row, and so on.

I need to perform operations on individual arrays belonging to two separate rows of this matrix at the same index. For example, if I want to perform an operation on the 2nd array segment of the 1st and 10th row, I would pick the 2nd and 74th elements from the data vector respectively. The array elements will always be from the same array segment.

This operation is performed a number of times with different row pairs and when the number of rows in the matrix is small, I don't see any issues with the performance. However, when the number of rows is significant, I'm seeing a significant degradation in performance, which I attribute to frequent cache misses.

Is there a way to custom align my struct along the cache line to reduce cache misses without changing the struct definition? I want to control the layout of elements in memory at a fine-grained level like keeping elements that are 8 elements apart in cache(if 64 is the width of the matrix).

I used the `repr(align(x))` attribute to specify the alignment of a struct but I think it's not helping as I think it's keeping array elements in a sequential fashion and in the case of a big matrix the respective elements might not be there in the cache.

Comment: "Is there a way to custom align my struct along the cache line to reduce cache misses without changing the struct definition?" The only thing you can do there is increase the padding, which would *increase* the cache misses as you'd have less rows fitting in cache. And as calfce25 notes that requires changing the structure definition since attributes on a struct affect the struct itself, you can't set an attribute to affect an item 3-deep.

Answer (score 1):

`#[repr(align)]` can only affect the items stored in the struct (The `Vec` pointer, length and capacity plus your `width`), but since `Vec` is little more than a pointer to the data the layout behind it is entirely dictated by it's implementation and there is no way for you to directly affect it. So "without changing the struct definition" it's not possible to change the layout. You can however create a custom `Vec`-like or manage the memory yourself directly in the `RowMatrix`